# Add custom button in custom module magento

Tags: magento

I am creating custom module in Magento. I want to add a custom button and  send it to any.phtml file. Please guide me how doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have proper knowledge of creating module in Magento.
Refer these links to understand and create module

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Now to be specific to your question. You can not redirect to any.phtml. You have to redirect to such a controller action which has included any.phtml in its layout. That you can find in above links that how to link phtml and controller action.